# ES6 imports using module names without path

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I would like to be able to import my modules using just name without path.

For example, say I want to use:

```
import ViewportChecker from 'viewport-checker';
```

instead of

```
import ViewportChecker from '../ViewportChecker';
```

But I want to keep the file where it is and not create a new npm module of it. Would it be possible to define it as module for exmaple in package.json?

Comment: There's nothing special about ES6 import syntax here. How the identifier string is resolved to a module depends only on the environment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use webpack's alias feature : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias

Answer (score 1):

You can put a default file with naming convention of `index.js` which contains all the exports.

like:

```
-App
--home
---index.js // <--it will hold all the exports from otherClass.js and anotherClass.js
---otherClass.js
---anotherClass.js
```

Now you have to import just folder name and it will automatically search for index.js file to get the particular exported item.

It might look like this:

```
import Home from './home';
```

Comment: how does it work? in my understanding it would look like import {Home} from './index'; which is actually a valid solution in my case

Comment: when requiring a directory, it's index.js file will be used. This is just how node does it